# Generating a graph with increasing density

Tags: c++, graph

I'm try to create a function that will generate random graphs with increasing number of edges. To ensure the graph remains connected and that there is at least one path between any two vertices, I'm initially connecting all the vertices in my graph like a "chain", then adding random edges to that chain.

I'm wondering if my function is doing what I think it's doing (appears to be for small graphs, but it's hard to verify for larger ones), and also if there are any suggestions on a better way to do this? I feel like my approach is inefficient.

```
//Generate a random graph
void Graph::generate(int numEdges) {
    int currentEdges = 0;
    int v1 = rand() % numVertices-1;

    //Pick destination vertex. If 0 randomly generated, just add 1 to it
    /*int dest = rand() % numVertices;
    if (dest != 0) {
        destination = dest;
    } else {
        destination = 1;
    }*/

    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices-1; i++) {
        adjList[i].push_back(i+1);
        adjList[i+1].push_back(i);
        matrix[i][i+1] = 1;
        matrix[i+1][i] = 1;
    }

    while(currentEdges < numEdges-(numVertices-1)) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            if(currentEdges == numEdges) {
                break;
            }
            v1 = rand() % numVertices;
            if (edgeExists(i, v1) == true || i == v1) {

            } else {
                adjList[i].push_back(v1);
                adjList[v1].push_back(i);
                matrix[i][v1] = 1;
                matrix[v1][i] = 1;
                currentEdges++;
            //cout << "Added " << i << " to " << v1 << " list" << endl;
            //cout << "Added " << v1 << " to " << i << " list" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your way will not generate uniform distribution.

Comment: If you pass it a `numEdges` that is greater than `numVertices*(numVertices-1)/2`, you'll have a long wait.